# Implementing half precision floating point data type in OpenCL kernel

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, kernel, opencl

I have OpenCL device that doesn't have the extension cl_khr_fp16 supported and I need to use two bytes floating point data type instead of four in order to save memory (private and local memory).

Is there any method so I can implement half precision floating point data type manually so that I can for example use:

```
my_half x[1024]={0};
//.. later in my code
x[0]=float_to_half(0.5f*0.3f);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you know the binary memory layout of floats is the same "endianess" as a 32-bit int, then you can use a combination of `ldexp()` and `frexp()` from `<math.h>` to make your `float_to_half` and `half_to_float` functions.  If not, you can use the above, along with an extra scale to put the binary point where you want it and then cast to `(short)`.  Some care will be needed for negative, zero and out-of-range values.

Comment: you **could** use some magic using a class containing two `char`s, but I doubt it'll be worth it

Answer (score 1):

The **cl_khr_fp16** extension adds support for half scalar and vector types as built-in types that can be used for arithmetic operations, conversions, etc.

Even *without* that extension, you can still **store** half types in buffers and images, and convert to (regular) float when reading and from float when writing (then do your math using floats). For buffers, use loads from a pointer to a half and stores to a pointer to a half (using the
vload_half, vload_halfn, vloada_halfn and vstore_half, vstore_halfn, vstorea_halfn functions). For images, use the CL_HALF_FLOAT type, and read_imagef/write_imagef.